# Creating a Scala.js Library - linking the Scala to the Javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I'm trying to write a new library that would work in Scala.js. I have written some of the implementations of the classes and methods in Javascript. How do I set it up so that a user can code in Scala.js (Scala)?

I've looked at some Scala.js libraries on GitHub, but these do not show the Javascript code; they all appear to be .scala files.

So how does one actually create a new library for Scala.js?

**Edit:** The main code for the library must be written in Javascript since it takes advantage of the Javascript audio api.

Comment: There are relevant docs: [calling JavaScript from Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/export-to-javascript.html) or [exporting scala.js API to javascript](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/export-to-javascript.html) (nor clear which one from your description)

Comment: Indeed. Additionally, to answer the "The main code for the library must be written in Javascript since it takes advantage of the Javascript audio api.": No it doesn't. Scala.js is precisely very good at letting you call arbitrary JavaScript APIs directly from your .scala code. See the first link given by @om-nom-nom for this use case.

Comment: Both of @om-nom-nom links seem to be the same (exporting), the first link should be [calling JavaScript from Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html).

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat agreeing with the comment from [@sjrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829647/sjrd), it should be possible to write your JavaScript-targeted API directly within Scala.js (See [Calling JavaScript from Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html) ).

Alternatively, there may also be the possibility for 'importing' or converting your existing JavaScript code into Scala.js '.scala' files in a strongly-typed-Scala manner, so:

1. Convert your JavaScript file to [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org), start by changing the file extension from '.js' to '.ts'.
2. Process your [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) file(s) 
   created in #1 into valid Scala[JS] files using [@sjrd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829647/sjrd) (!) [TypeScript-to-ScalaJS 
   importer @ Github](https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js-ts-importer).
3. Finally, develop your code against Scala.js, using the '.scala' 
   files generated in #2

As [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) is a strongly-typed superset of JavaScript, changing the extension alone might be enough - otherwise, after running and failing step #2, you might need to refine you TypeScript'd library, this post, 'How to compile plain *.js (JavaScript) files with the TypeScript Compiler', should help with that.

The ['DefinitelyTyped' code repository @ Github](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) contains a collection of JavaScript libraries updated to [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org), the [webaudio API](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/webaudio) is one of them (so this could be converted and used within Scala.JS using some of the process outlined above).

I *haven't* [yet] personally tested this myself, in anger, **I'd be interested in whether you get any mileage out of this tool set/process**.

Here are some extra TypeScript resources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/12/31/definitive-guide-to-typescript